# Puppet's Exec[] ignoring onlyif?

Tags: puppet

I'm experiencing a very strange behavior with Puppet's Exec type.

I have two similar `Exec[]` in a class, both with the `onlyif` parameter, as you can see below. The problem is `Exec['apt-update']` is always performed (i.e. every time Puppet's agent apply its manifests), even when the `onlyif` condition is false, unlike `Exec['install-newrelic-apt-key']` that works fine.

*Note: my `Exec[]`'s path ($PATH) is configured outside this class and all commands works as expected in command line*

```
class newrelic::server($license_key) {
  file { "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/newrelic.list":
    ensure  => present,
    content => "deb http://apt.newrelic.com/debian/ newrelic non-free",
  }

  exec { "apt-update":
    command => "aptitude update",
    onlyif  => "test 0 -eq $(dpkg -l | grep -c newrelic-sysmond)",
    require => File['/etc/apt/sources.list.d/newrelic.list'],
  }

  exec { "install-newrelic-apt-key":
    command => "apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://subkeys.pgp.net --recv-keys 548C16BF",
    onlyif  => "test 0 -eq $(apt-key list | grep -c 548C16BF)",
  }

  package { "newrelic-sysmond": 
    ensure  => latest,
    require => [
        Exec["install-newrelic-apt-key"],
        Exec["apt-update"],
    ],
  }

  file { "/etc/newrelic/nrsysmond.cfg":
    ensure  => present,
    content  => template("newrelic/nrsysmond.erb"),
    owner   => "root",
    group   => "newrelic",
    mode    => "0640",
    notify  => Service["newrelic-sysmond"],
  }

  service { "newrelic-sysmond":
    ensure    => running,
    enable    => true,
    hasstatus => true,
    require   => Package["newrelic-sysmond"],
  }
}
```

** The code above is public domain, feel free to use it as you want.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually everything is right with the manifest, but it just *started work as expected after I've restarted the puppet agent process*.

Sounds like a bug in Puppet for me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe your `onlyif` commands will undergo the shell interpolation you're expecting.  I would try switching to an `unless` statement as so:

```
class newrelic::server($license_key) {
  file { "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/newrelic.list":
    ensure  => present,
    content => "deb http://apt.newrelic.com/debian/ newrelic non-free",
  }

  exec { "apt-update":
    command => "aptitude update",
    unless  => "dpkg -l | grep -c newrelic-sysmond",
    require => File['/etc/apt/sources.list.d/newrelic.list'],
  }

  exec { "install-newrelic-apt-key":
    command => "apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://subkeys.pgp.net --recv-keys 548C16BF",
    unless => "apt-key list | grep -c 548C16BF",
  }

  package { "newrelic-sysmond": 
    ensure  => latest,
    require => [
        Exec["install-newrelic-apt-key"],
        Exec["apt-update"],
    ],
  }

  file { "/etc/newrelic/nrsysmond.cfg":
    ensure  => present,
    content  => template("newrelic/nrsysmond.erb"),
    owner   => "root",
    group   => "newrelic",
    mode    => "0640",
    notify  => Service["newrelic-sysmond"],
  }
```

Comment: I'm going to try "unless", but why Exec["install-newrelic-apt-key"] works?

Comment: Well, with unless is working fine! Thanks a lot @gabrtv! But still it is unclear why with onlyif does not works...

Comment: Wow, actually it is not working! puppet continues logging `Jun  8 13:09:41 proxy puppet-agent[31841]: (/Stage[main]/Newrelic::Server/Exec[apt-update]/returns) executed successfully`, and just for `Exec['apt-update']`

Comment: I've discovered the mystery! Actually the manifest was right, but it just started work as expected after I restart the puppet agent process. Strange, no? Sounds like a bug for me.

Comment: @semente glad you figured it out! hard to say what the exact cause was.. though it sounds like the actual puppet code was right.  if you can reproduce it you should file an issue at http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/issues

Comment: thank you very much @gabrtv! I could not reproduce it, but I'll keep an eye on it. :-)